# Deploying error with capistrano: "bundler: not executable: cap"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler

I am supposed to work on a quite antique Ruby On Rails project to make some minor (mostly HTML and CSS) changes on some webpages. I did not work with Ruby On Rails before and I am just getting into it.

I have cloned the project via git from github and installed all gems via 'bundler install'. Note that I am using an old version of Ruby (1.8.7) since I was told the project would not work with a newer version. Note also I am on Windows 7 and the project was built with Mac OS X.

Now I am trying to get the changes I made to the live site (after commiting and pushing the changes to the git repository) with Capistrano (Installed and Version 2.8.0)  which should be possible with

```
bundle exec cap production deploy
```

However when I try this I just get:

```
bundler: not executable: cap
```

Any ideas what is going wrong here? Thanks alot in advance!

Kind regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `capisrano` is not defined as a gem in a project's `Gemfile`. Try installing the gem with `gem install capistrano`.

You can also check if Capistrano is installed on your system by running `cap -T` in your project folder. This should give you a list of all tasks in that project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but capistrano is already installed, so this should not be the issue.

`cap -V -> Capistrano v2.8.0`

and `cap -T` brings up the tasks as you said without any problems.

Comment: Capistrano is however also defined in the gemfile under `group :development do ... gem 'capistrano' gem 'capistrano-ext' ... end` if that changes anything.